# How do i replace a string using regex?

Tags: regex, wordpress

How do i completely remove the following strings from my wordpress posts using regex?

> NOTE: THESE ARE TEXT STRINGS THAT GOT HARDCODED WHEN I REIMPORTED MY
>   POSTS.

Below are 3 examples however there can be 100s.

Here is the criteria: string starts with:
     `googletag.cmd.push`

String ends with:
    `"); });`

examples:

```
 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-cBdL_cggQrHX7u2qnNrMtQ"); });

 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-y_rI3cXW4HPKVfyNbLcmjg"); });

 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-TOILczxQd6hUhdv1UN5ETA"); });
```

Comment: Are you trying to cheat google ads?

Comment: No i exported posts from my old site. Now when i export them back in somehow this tag was saved as text. I used wp-import and wp-export.

Comment: what tool are you using to do the regex replace?

Comment: I am planning on using wordpress plugin search regex (https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/). However the data is in a custom field, if there is a better way to remove it i'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

The regex to match your above examples is as simple as this

```
googletag\.cmd\.push\(.*?\); }\);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CBVqIw/1